# alert/confirm doesn't work in chrome app - missing config?

Tags: json, google-chrome-app

I made a chrome app to display my web by `webview` tag, but the js API `alert()/confirm()` doesn't work. That made me wondering. Chrome app needs to config something to support confirm?

this is my manifest.json:

```
{
"app": {
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
},
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Performance Monitor",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "A performance monitor to show cpu and memory status.",
"icons": {
    "16": "img/ccloud.png",
    "48": "img/ccloud.png",
    "128": "img/ccloud.png"
},
"permissions": [
    "webview"
],
"webview": {
    "partitions": [
        {
            "name": "static",
            "accessible_resources": ["header.html", "footer.html", "static.png"]
        },
        {
            "name": "trusted*",
            "accessible_resources": ["local_*.html", "*.png", "*.js"]
        },
        {
            "name": "trusted-audio",
            "accessible_resources": ["*.mp3"]
        }
    ]
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#event-dialog

Comment: Thanks a lot,and I met a new problem,I find that window.alert/confirm didn't work.Did chrome app remove the api?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alert dialog from <webview> was blocked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30549198/alert-dialog-from-webview-was-blocked)

Comment: @elonhu https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_deprecated